# Swapping transmitter and receiver locations

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics, radio

Pardon me if this is a silly question, because I don't quite study RF.

Let's say I have a set of transmitter (radio + antenna) and a set of receiver (radio + antenna), at location A and B respectively. Then I transmit a signal at a certain power, for example 5W, and I measured the signal at the receiver, say 3.4W, due to losses incurred when it travels from point A to B.

Then, I swapped the locations of the transmitter and receiver. I have also rotated the antennas by 180 degrees, this is to ensure consistent gain at the angle towards the other antenna, if directional antennas are used (I'm not sure if I'm making sense here).

Will this result in the same received power (i.e. same loss)? What are some things that would affect the results and that I have overlooked?